# creating a transparent fragment over an opaque fragment in android

Tags: android

I have a view   below which there is another view. 
I want my top view to be transparent so that the view below is visible as well.

So my top view occupies the whole screen but I want half of this view to be transparent so the view below becomes visible .

This is what I have already tried  :

1. Setting background of the view to null (shows view according to the theme of the app)
2. Setting translucent theme for activity  makes the whole activity transparent
3. Setting transparent color to background doesnt work as well.    (The background becomes grey or black based on theme)

   4.Setting alpha has the same effect as the third one.

Here is my default app theme :

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure this is has been answered before.  This is how I make a transparent dialog fragment which shows over other fragments.  In onCreateView set the window background to transparent.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_fragment_pager,
            container);
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
    return view;
}
```

colors.xml a color with transparency.  example rounded_container_bg is 0x22/0xFF percent transparent.

```
<color name="rounded_container_bg">#22000000</color>
```

Set the background of the fragment to the transparent color.

```
android:background="@color/rounded_container_bg"
```

Comment: based on your answer ,i realized i was not clear enough with my question ,so i have edited the question. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the layout of your fragment.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score -1):

there are a few ways I can think of to reach your goal.
depend on how you want to approach it.

1. you can set your desired fragment main layout visibility to GONE.
   you can achieve it in code like this :

   ```
   android:visibility="gone"
   ```

or in java :

```
yourLayoutName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); <-- to show it
yourLayoutName.setVisibility(View.GONE); <-- to hide it
```

2. you can also set your background to transparent, though it won't make any buttons, texts and content disappear with it.
   just the layout background color.